# Matlab get transfer function from Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, transfer-function

[image]

Is it possible to use MATLAB to retrieve the data from Simulink from this block diagram and plot the transfer function?

I have already tried using `tf`, but that did not work.

```
res = sim("Test.slx");
G = tf(res.simout.data,res.in.data);
```

Comment: Do not add code in comments please. Those are ephemeral and subject to deletion, as well as being hard to read. Instead, [edit] the question to include the code. Be sure to [format](/help/formatting) it properly. As to the code itself: what does "did not work" mean? Did it throw an error, were the results incorrect, did your computer explode ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the Linearization tool? Example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize-simulink-model.html)